# How to get records created between timeframe in a report

Tags: reporting, datetime, timezone, time

I need to create a report of all the records between 7am to 5pm CST/CDT everyday. How can I achieve this?

The solution I tried -

1. Created a formula field which extracts Hours from created date (Returns hours in GMT)
2. Created a formula that checks the GMT in CST Time range.

How can I make this formula dynamic to take Daylight savings in consideration? Is there another/better approach? Please advise. Thanks.